# return a PHP object to an ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, oop

I'm learning PHP OOP, and getting used to all of these objects.

When I create an object in a PHP file called via an `$.ajax` function, I want to deliver the answer back. But how am I supposed to send back the object to my ajax call ? Before OOP, I was putting everything into an array, then `json_encode()` the array, and everything worked perfectly. How to adapt this using OOP?

Thanks a lot for your answers
Romain

Example:

**On the client side**

```
$.ajax(
{
  url:"test.php",
  type:"POST",
  dataType:"json",
  success:function(json)
  {
    // json into template
  }
});
```

**On the server side**: `test.php`

```
require_once("bdd.php");

function loadClass($class)
{
    require $class.".class.php";
}

spl_autoload_register('loadClass');

$PersonneM = new PersonneManager($db);

$perso = $PersonneM->get("123456");

$perso = serialize($perso); // ????????????

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array("result",$perso));
```

Comment: Your success function syntax is incorrect. It should be: `success: function(json) { . . . }`.

Comment: Yes sorry. That was not the problem anyway

Comment: My guess is that you meant `echo json_encode(array("result"=>$perso));` in the last line. and also - there is no need to `serialize` the object - `json_encode` knows how to handle custom objects (it will take all the `public` properties)

Answer (score 0):

either use serialize or __toString to create a JSON-representation of your data that you can send down the tube. You will not be needing an extra array around your object.

However, there is an error in some JSON parsers/interpreters that can mess with your data when not wrapped in an array. But I haven't heared anything of this issue since a couple of years so you should be safe

Comment: You should also note PHP works in `lowerCamelCase` so `$PersonneM` would be invalid markup. It should be `$personneM`